# How I can get one column value from a table?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I use Spring boot and Spring Data.

I have a contact entity with the id and firstName columns.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Contact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


}
```

I use repository with Spring Data to find my data.

```
 public interface contactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, Long> {
    }
```

My controller, example with getAll:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllContact", produces = "application/json")
public List<Contact> getAllClients(){
    return repo.getAll();
}
```

My controller works but I don't know how to return all values in column firstName in my controller. I tried with a query, It works but it only returns a list of values and not the json:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT firstName FROM Contact" )
        List<Contact> findAllFirstName();
```

Example:

```
["Pierre", "Jean"]
```

And i want this (in Json):

```
[{"firstName ": "Pierre" },{"firstName ":"Jean"}]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the projection and excerpt support in Spring Data Rest. Whilst adding in JsonIgnore annotations does work, it's inflexible as you can only ignore at compile time not run time.

See

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jackson libraries are in your classpath. Then add @ResponseBody in your controller method to return json output. Also add @JsonIgnore in id in your entity to exclude it from json output.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllContact", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Contact> getAllClients(){
    return repo.getAll();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Contact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;
    private String firstName;

    .....
}
```